# basement drywall over vertical brick surface

Tags: drywall, framing, mold

I'm attaching drywall to the studs in my basement.  The wall's frame of studs is standing on top of a tiny wall of bricks, one brick deep.  The bricks were already there, acting to dam water so it would flow towards a sump pump.  We've stopped the leak by fixing our grade in the yard, so water doesn't come in anymore.

My question is this: When I put up the drywall, is it ok if the bottom edge touches the brick (vertically by just going up against it)?  Or would moisture from the brick seep up and mold the drywall?  If so, can I prevent this with some kind of plastic shield?

Please see the pictures, and let me know if you'd like any more information.

[image: frame on bricks]

[image: frame on bricks 2]

Comment: you should have plastic under the wood

Comment: @jsotola Should I also put plastic between the wood/brick and the sheetrock?